# Docker secret not mounting to default location

Tags: docker, powershell, azure-devops, docker-compose, azure-pipelines

I'm using docker-compose to produce a docker image which requires access to a secure Azure Artifacts directory via Paket. As I'm sure at least some people are aware, Paket does not have default compatibility with the Azure Artifacts Credential Provider. To gain the access I need, I'm trying to mount the access token produced by the credential provider as a secret, then consume it using `cat` within a `paket config` command. `cat` then returns an error message stating that the file is not found at the default secret location.

I'm running this code within an Azure Pipeline on the Microsoft-provided `ubuntu-latest` agent.

Here's the relevant code snippets (It's possible I'm going into too much detail...):

`docker-compose.ci.build.yml`:

```
version: '3.6'

services:
  ci_build:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: <IMAGE IDENTITY>
    secrets:
      - azure_credential

secrets:
  azure_credential:
    file: ./credential.txt
```

`dockerfile`:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0.102-bullseye-slim-amd64 AS build
<LABEL maintainer="<Engineering lead>"

WORKDIR /src
<Various COPY instructions>
RUN dotnet tool restore
RUN dotnet paket restore
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=azure_credential dotnet paket config add-token "<ARTIFACT_FEED_URL>" "$(cat /run/secrets/azure_credential)"
```

Azure pipeline definition YAML:

```
jobs:
  - job: BuildPublish
    displayName: Build & Publish
    steps:
      - task: PowerShell@2
        displayName: pwsh build.ps1
        inputs:
          filePath: ${{ parameters.workingDirectory }}/.azure-pipelines/build.ps1
          pwsh: true
          workingDirectory: ${{ parameters.workingDirectory }}
        env:
          SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
```

The relevant lines of the powershell script initiating docker-compose:

```
$projectRoot = Split-Path -Path $PSScriptRoot -Parent
Push-Location -Path $projectRoot
try {
    ...
    Out-File -FilePath ./credential.txt -InputObject $Env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN
    ...
    & docker-compose -f ./docker-compose.ci.build.yml build
    ...
}
finally {
    ...
    Pop-Location
}
```

The error message:
`0.276 cat: /run/secrets/azure_credential: No such file or directory`

If there's other relevant code, let me know.

I tried to verify that the environment variable I'm housing the secret in on the agent even existed and that the value was being saved to the `./credential.txt` file for mounting in the image. I verified that the text file was being properly created. I've tried fiddling with the syntax for all the relevant commands--fun fact, Docker docs have two different versions of the mounting syntax, but the other version just crashed. I tried using Windows default pathing in case my source image was a Windows one, but it doesn't appear to be.

Essentially, here's where I've left it: I know that the file `./credential.txt` exists and contains some value. I know my mounting syntax is correct, or Docker would crash. The issue appears to be something to do with the default mounting path and/or how docker-compose embeds its secrets.

Comment: This might help you for the paths of secrets: https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/#windows-support

Comment: @AntoineBaqain I did look there and tried the windows path described. Not only did it not work, it failed to use the backslashes as pathing characters. I can only assume that this means my image is running a unix environment.

Comment: try this, move the "cat" command into entrypoint script on the image, and see how it works. Per what I read, it seems like secrets are available on windows in runtime and not build time.

Comment: @AntoineBaqain from what I saw in the docs, the mount flag only works on RUN instructions. I'm not sure how I would go about even trying to mount the secret in an ENTRYPOINT instruction.

Comment: What I mean, don't mount, as per docs, the secrets are made available for the container in windows as files, so in runtime you would only do the cat command for adding the token, currently your cat is in build script. 
All examples are showing that files are read on runtime in the container.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. For reasons I do not understand, the path to the mounted secret has to be defined as an environment variable in the docker-compose YAML. So, like this:

```
version: '3.6'

services:
  ci_build:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: <IMAGE IDENTITY>
    secrets:
      - azure_credential
    environment:
      AZURE_CREDENTIAL_FILE: /run/secrets/azure_credential

secrets:
  azure_credential:
    file: credential.txt
```

This solved the issue. If anyone knows *why* this solved the issue, I'd love to hear.

Comment: Well, assuming this a build-time secret, `secrets` should be nested under `build`. The service level `secrets` would be for stuff at runtime and [per the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/#build-support-for-docker-secrets-into-your-images) they do not create environment variables for those.

"Docker secrets do not set environment variables directly. This was a conscious decision, because environment variables can unintentionally be leaked between containers (for instance, if you use --link)."